# rsyslogd and system log output weird or normal?

Tags: command-line, syslog

currently I have this non-stop output in system log:

```
[   89.115236] FW REJECT (input): IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:23:5e:6f:ab:d9:08:00 SRC=10.158.0.1 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=389 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=51601 PROTO=UDP SPT=67 DPT=68 LEN=369
```

Is this normal or is there somebody behind ASA in Alabama trying to sniff at mine eth0 ?

When I activate `ipkungfu --panic`
then it disappears after a while, but when ipkungfu --panic is switched off, then
it comes back ... ???

who is that ? how can I find out more ?

Comment: Isn't 10.158.0.1 your router?

Comment: no it is not a router - it is address of ASA - leading to a supercomputer - would like to know, how to trace on from there ?

Answer (score 1):

From that syslog line I can tell you the host 10.158.0.1 (SRC=10.158.0.1) is broadcasting (DST=255.255.255.255) a UDP packet (PROTO=UDP) from port 67 (SPT=67) to port (DPT=68).

Port 67/UDP and 68/UDP are used by DHCP server client respectively.

This is the expected behavior if the ASA firewall is a DHCP server. That logged packet can be a DHCP Offer or a DHCP acknowledgement.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Comment: is this normal, that system log is NOT scrolling perpetually ( should watching the traffic without pause ? ) at present system log is not scrolling ? when I do apt-get install --reinstall rsyslogd then it is scrolling again ?

Comment: now I have this output today ? : cracklib: no dictionary update necessary.

Comment: @dschinn1001 I think it's a regular auto-update of cracklib. Might the first time that you noticed. "On Debian systems, pam_cracklib's dictionaries live in /var/cache/cracklib and are rebuilt nightly by the
/usr/sbin/update-cracklib script." Source http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html